# Problem with login / Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications, iis-7.5

I am facing a problem in [my running website](http://www.askiitians.com/) during login. When i am going to login from my username/password it is working some times but some times it shows the old thread data. This problem happens with other users also.

Also on my forum section same problem occurs when I am viewing the forum post after that if I am viewing another thread(post) same data is showing same as last thread(post).

Can anyone help me what type. Is this problem related with sql caching/IIS Connection Pooling??  If so then how to solve it.?

Comment: You're going to have to post some code and show an error message. You have provided no basis for others to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it will works some times but not works all time", the page show some error? what kind of error?

I suggest you have to test your SQL Queries for some possible error, try all the 'cases of use'. If you are using some Session Vars or Viewstate Vars, you must be sure that they have data, or not, because some times this cause some strange behaviors (some cases with Viewstate vars in pagination).

PS: Sorry for my bad english.